# How to play a compressed video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to play the compressed video in HTML? I getting the file from API.
Andriod compressed code is:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath,"-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-s", "160x120", "-r", "24", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "150k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath};
```

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Answer (score 0):

How to play a video in HTML, just as your title asks:

```
<video id="yourMovie" src="filepath" controls></video>
```

Although the code snippet you posted is not javascript, are you working with JSP?